# How can I create a caption system?

Tags: unity

I will not be voice acting my game, so I'd like to add captions/subtitles to it.

How could I achieve this?

I'm using Unity 2018.

Comment: When submitting your question, please elaborate on your situation.  Are you looking into multi language support?  How much research have you done so far to assist the community in guiding you.

Comment: Do you really want to know "Is there a way.." - ie. do you expect the answer could be "no, there is no way, it's utterly impossible" and would you really be satisfied with that answer? Or do you actually want to know "How can I build..."? If you want help building something, you'll need to tell us about the requirements. What kind of game events should trigger subtitles/captions to display? Do you have an existing data source you're drawing the text from, or is that source part of what you need to build? What have you tried so far in the way of putting UI text on the screen? Did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Use an overlay Canvas with a text box. Put a MonoBehaviour subclass (eg Subtitles) on the textbox that you can use to display your text. A minimal example would be something like:

```
public class Subtitles : MonoBehaviour {
  public Text textbox;
  private static Subtitles Instance;
  void Start() { Instance = this; }
  public static void ShowText(string text) {
      Instance.textbox.text = text;
  }
}
```

Then when you want to show a message, just call `Subtitles.ShowText("my message");`